# How to pass Object through vue router as prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

So I've got a vue router and for one of the views, I want to pass a prop of type Object, but when I pass the prop, it ends up not as an object but as `[object Object]`.

Heres how I set up the route for this page:

```
{
    path: '/blogpage/',
    name: 'BlogPage',
    component: () => import('../subviews/BlogPage.vue'),
    props: (route) => ({
        blog: route.params.blog,
        ...route.params
    })
  }
```

Here's the view I'm trying to go to:

```
<template>
    <div class="page" v-on:click="test">
        AJSFHDKOIFHNK
        {{blog}}
        <h1>{{ blog.title }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'BlogPage',
    props: {
        blog: Object,
    },
}
</script>
```

And the first tag of my router link going there:

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'BlogPage', 
           params: { blog: blog }}">
```

For now, I'm using dummy data for the blog page and the dummy blog object looks like this:

```
{
    title: 'Blog Post 1',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis temporibus exercitationem aut unde provident mollitia?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex optio, quas doloribus impedit aut cum expedita molestiae beatae incidunt similique, aliquam ea nemo exercitationem libero atque sunt autem. Inventore, nostrum veritatis. Nostrum eum aliquid soluta praesentium ullam distinctio temporibus eius doloremque dicta doloribus, et labore vitae odio impedit maiores ratione!',
    date: '2018-01-01',
    author: 'John Doe',
    id: "90876tygui"
}
```

Right now, the BlogPage view looks like this and the h1 has no text:
[image]

Comment: So the object is in the route parameters?

Comment: Yes i think so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the object is in the route parameters and you're not using the composition API, in your view's `<script>` tag, you can add the `blog` object to the `data` object.

```js
export default {
    name: 'BlogPage',
    data: function() {
        return {
            blog: this.$route.params.blog,
        };
    },
}
```

But, because you're passing in the object via the route parameters, which only accepts strings, the object is converted to its string representation: `[object Object]`. To work around this, first, you need to change the parameter to be a string version of the object. This can be accomplished with `JSON.stringify`. So your `<router-link>` turns into `<router-link :to="{ name: 'BlogPage', params: { blog: JSON.stringify(blog) }}">`. Then, you have to update the data object in the view by parsing the passed in object with `JSON.parse`. To do this, replace `this.$route.params.blog` with `JSON.parse(this.$route.params.blog)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but unfortunately the result is still the same, when i do `{{blog}}` in the template in BlogPage, it still displays as [object Object] in the form of a string.

Comment: the data is getting through to the BlogPage component both through your method and through the method I previously used, but the problem is that the object is being converted into the string "[object Object]" somewhere along the way.

Comment: What does the object look like?

Comment: I've edited my question to include additional information.

Comment: It will always return "[object Object]" because that's the string representation of an object. If you want the object to be outputted, use `{{ JSON.stringify(blog) }}` in place of `{{ blog }}`. The alternative is to add an element for each key/value pair with `v-text` bindings, which is what I do.

Comment: I'm sorry but all that does is wrap [object Object] in parenthesis. I know that the object wasn't converted to [object Object] in the BlogPage because I get a warning in the console each time i go to the blogPage that says "Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "blog". Expected Object, got String with value "[object Object]"."

Comment: Oh! The route parameter can't be an object, it has to be a string. So when you add the parameter, it converts it to a string. So when you add it to the parameter, in your `<router-link>` tag, you need to put the `JSON.stringify(blog)` there. Which will make it: `<router-link :to="{ name: 'BlogPage', params: { blog: JSON.stringify(blog) }}">`. Then, in the view, Replace `this.$route.params.blog` with `JSON.parse(this.$route.params.blog)`.

Comment: Does anyone have link to documentation which specifies this string-passing and reason behind it? In Vue2 router it was possible to pass an object. It just feels bit strange that this was suppressed. I understand the reason when we consider passing data via query-string as key-value-pairs, but I don't understand why object-passing was removed on vue3 router?

Comment: Still, alternative solution: You could always store object within Vuex-store state. Only problem is the need to clear this after route has been loaded.

Comment: Some more context for further reading here: https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/494